# Huawei Mobile Services In-app Purchases failed to load products once published in AppGallery

Tags: in-app-purchase, huawei-mobile-services, huawei-developers, appgallery, huawei-iap

I integrated the HMS Core In-App Purchase service, and it works as expected in the sandbox test environment. However, the moment that I publish to the Huawei AppGallery, none of my products load and I get an error "failed to get data". I've done a few tests to see what the issue could be, and I'm pretty sure the code has been setup correctly. The problem always occurs once the app gets upload to AppGallery, and I'm starting to think that's where the problem is. Does anyone have any ideas on what's going on here?

Answer (score 0):

Please check as follows:

1. Ensure that the certificate fingerprint has been configured, and the certificate for packing the signature on the local client is the same as the certificate for configuring the fingerprint in [AppGallery Connect](https://developer.huawei.com/consumer/en/service/josp/agc/index.html).
2. Please check  that your service location is the same as the location where your HUAWEI ID was registered. To check the registration location, go to **Account center** > **Settings** > **About**. To check your service location, go to **AppGallery** > **Me** > **Settings** > **Country**/**Region**.

To give more precise solution, please provide the log.

Answer (score 0):

This might be an app signature issue. Please check the documentation for App Signing.
https://developer.huawei.com/consumer/en/doc/development/AppGallery-connect-Guides/agc-app_bundle

App Signing automatically generates a signature key which will automatically override the signature of any APK you submit. If you signed your app with your local keystore and registered it as the signature you're using for your app with App Signing is enabled, there will be a signature mismatch. AppGallery will write over the signature you put on your APK and put the one that is generated with App Signing.

Here are two separate solutions for this issue. Use the one that works the best for you.

1. Make sure the signature key that is registered to your app is the one generated by App Signing.
2. Disable App Signing.

Comment: I checked my app settings, I did enabled App Signing by mistake. I disabled it and resubmitted the app for review again, hopefully it with work once approved.